# BibTeX dá erro em abreviação

Tags: latex

Estou tendo problemas em colocar o nome das revistas nas minhas citações.  O seguinte erro aparece:

```
? ! Undefined control sequence.
l.103 \newblock {\em \apj}, 615:209--221, Nov. 2004.
```

O termo `\apj` acima tem o mesmo papel do `\mnras` no exemplo abaixo.

Um exemplo de um artigo que eu cito segue abaixo

```
@ARTICLE{kauffmann,
  author = {{Kauffmann}, G. and {White}, S.~D.~M. and {Heckman}, T.~M. and 
  {M{\'e}nard}, B. and {Brinchmann}, J. and {Charlot}, S. and 
  {Tremonti}, C. and {Brinkmann}, J.},
  title = "{The environmental dependence of the relations between stellar mass, structure, star formation and nuclear activity in galaxies}",
  journal = {\mnras},
  eprint = {astro-ph/0402030},
  keywords = {galaxies: evolution, galaxies: formation, galaxies: stellar content},
  year = 2004,
  month = sep,
  volume = 353,
  pages = {713-731},
  doi = {10.1111/j.1365-2966.2004.08117.x},
  adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2004MNRAS.353..713K},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

O problema está em `journal = {\mnras}`, a questão é: como eu faço para a abreviação `\mnras` funcionar?

Sobre o estilo de bibliografia que eu estou usando: já testei `n` estilos e nenhum funcionou.

Comment: Dúvida sobre seu texto: ali onde diz `já teste N estilos`, esse N quer dizer "vários"?

Comment: É exatamente isso.

Comment: Acho que é melhor trocar então. O ideal é deixar tudo o mais explicado possível de maneira que alguém que conheça do assunto possa responder tranquilamente sem precisar ficar pedindo mais informações. Quando você edita a pergunta, ela vai parar na primeira página, o que atrai mais visualizações (e possíveis respostas). Não vale editar por editar, mas informações extra são sempre bem-vindas. Por acaso não tem outras tags relevantes que você possa adicionar na pergunta?

Comment: Olá. Eu não entendi um detalhe: quando você diz que está tentando usar uma abreviação (`\mnras`), isso é um comando novo que você criou usando algum pacote de abreviação?